# List filtering comes back as 0, but it shouldn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've made a list and, in certain circumstances, the list is populated. Simple. However, when I try to filter the list based on a dropdown selection `ddlLeadCounty.SelectedItem.Value`, the count comes back as 0. This is definitely not true as I have manually checked that both the value in the dropdown and the value pulled into the list are the same.

Could any of you wise people see where it may be going wrong? I have tried both of the following methods to the same result.

c# .net code behind

```
myList = myList.FindAll(delegate(Partner part)
{
  return part.RegionId.Equals(ddlLeadCounty.SelectedItem.Value);
});
```

OR

```
myList = myList.Where(c => c.RegionId.Equals(ddlLeadCounty.SelectedItem.Value)).ToList();
```

Partner List:

```
public class Partner
{
    public int LeadOppCount;
    public string Guid;
    public int RegionId;

    public Partner(int LeadOppCount, string Guid, int RegionId)
    {
        this.LeadOppCount = LeadOppCount;
        this.Guid = Guid;
        this.RegionId = RegionId;
    }
}
```

Dropdown list example:

`<asp:ListItem value="100000004">Berkshire</asp:ListItem>`

In my tests, at least 1 list item definitely has a regionId of 100000004.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is the `Value` of the `SelectedItem`? What is the actual value? What type is `RegionId`? Does `myList` contain the value from the DDL?

Comment: When do you call the code above, in which event?  Is this WPF or WinForms?  Could you show us how you bind data to the dropdown?

Comment: amended with extra code. The dropdown is hardcoded. the Partner List is made on the fly.

Comment: Could you tell us the method that your first statement is contained in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you're I see `RegionId`, *I suppose* it's a `integer`, so write something like this **a pseudocode**:

```
int valueSelected = (int)ddlLeadCounty.SelectedItem.Value;
myList.FindAll(x=>x.RegionId == valueSelected );
```

In other words do not use `Equals`, for *possibly* boxed value in `SelectedValue`, but use concrete type.

*Should* work for you.

Comment: Quite right, mate. I should have thought of just doing that. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SelectedIndex.Value is a string value not an int so you will have to parse it.  The following line should work:

```
var myListFiltered = myList.Where(c => c.RegionId.Equals(int.Parse(ddlLeadCounty.SelectedItem.Value))).ToList();
```